# JQuery: change href link but ONLY on the next click

Tags: jquery, href, attr

Ok, so need a link changed via jquery. The code below works fine but it acts immediately. I need the link to become active only on the next click, not on the current click. Hope that makes sense?

Any help appreciated.

```
 $("#m-menu").click(function(){
$("#menu").animate({right: 0}, 500, "easeInOutCirc");
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME');
$(this).attr('href', 'http://backtohomepage.com');
 });
```

---

---

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers guys - its not quite as simple as an every-other-click solution and big apologies for not being clearer first time round. Here's the source page (I've not applied the above .attr code to this in order to better illustrate my requirement): http://joinersart.co.uk/mtest

Basically when the user clicks either the left/right arrows to navigate the gallery, you'll see the menu  bar shrinks. In order to get it back, you click "MENU". Once its back out again, the "MENU" text, changes to "HOME" and takes on a new function - link to the home page. Of course, if you click the left/right arrows again, it toggles back to "MENU" and changes its function back to expanding the menu bar. So basically this one link has two functions (either as a homepage link - "HOME", or as a menu bar expander - "MENU") depending on whether the menu bar is sticking out or tucked in.

When I try to apply the above .attr code, this is what happens - the user clicks the "MENU link and instead of the menu bar expanding, they are immediately taken to the home page. So it activates the link too soon .click function is executed. What I need it to do is to expand the menu bar and change the text from "MENU" to "HOME" first. Only THEN when the user clicks it, do they go to the home page.

Comment: What is the point of the first click? Or do you want to only respond to a double-click? Have you considered rebinding the click event from the callback of the animate method (assuming you only want it to behave differently once the animation is complete)?

Comment: What is it: `$(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME')`? The clause doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @VisioN - It makes perfect sense, it's just a tautology.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys - see my edit above.

Comment: You still haven't answered VisioN's question: why are you setting the text to the same thing that it already contains? Is that supposed to be a toggle? Can't you use similar logic to set the href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#m-menu').click(function () {
    // Do the work here
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).click(function () {
          $(this).attr('href', 'http://backtohomepage.com');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
$("#m-menu").one('click', function (){
    $("#m-menu").click(function(){
        $("#menu").animate({right: 0}, 500, "easeInOutCirc");
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME');
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://backtohomepage.com');
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Nope, `one` works differently. It requires an event to be bound.

Comment: One should bind the function, so the first click will act just like a normal one.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think he means you didn't specify an event.. ie.  `$(element).one('click',function()`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys - see my edit of question above.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```
var nbclicks = 0;
$("#m-menu").click(function(){
     $("#menu").animate({right: 0}, 500, "easeInOutCirc");
     if (nbclicks++==1) {
          $(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME');
          $(this).attr('href', 'http://backtohomepage.com');
     }
 });
```

Comment: This line is very strange : `$(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME');`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your click to occur once every to clicks??

If that's the case then you can do this

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#m-menu").click(function(){
        counter ++;
        if( counter % 2 == 0){
            $("#menu").animate({right: 0}, 500, "easeInOutCirc");
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'HOME' ? 'HOME' : 'HOME');
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://backtohomepage.com');
        }
     }); 

 });
```

This will make sure your code is executed on every even click

Comment: I know - apologies for that. Its not an easy problem to articulate so trying my best to keep it simple.